# Adding methods to Class when using Model-first in EntityFramework 5

Tags: entity-framework-5

In EF4, I would generate my model from the DB.  Then I would extend the classes using partials. This allowed me to regenerate from the DB without losing my code.

In EF5, when generating from the model, it creates a .cs file for every item in DB. I actually like this a lot more except, I am not sure what the best way to extend the objects is. If I write my changes right in the MyObj.cs file, I will lose them if I have to re-generate the model. I guess I chould create file MyObjPartial.cs and make the class partial there... thought?

~S

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the same pattern as before, by using a partial class. This is basically the same with all auto-generated file types and EF is not any different. You want to make sure you don't lose the changes when you regenerate the file.

Partial classes are also great in this example as a separation concept, that way you have the stuff that's important to your application separate to the stuff that's important for the running of Entity Framework